# Where does the details about the files is stored in android like its type, author etc

Tags: android, file, metadata

I can view the details about the file in details tab in android,where does these details actually stored in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can you MediaMetadataRetriever class for this...

Here is the reference link for same

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

Here is complete example

http://mrbool.com/how-to-extract-meta-data-from-media-file-in-android/28130
Hope this will helps you

Comment: I don't want to retrieve actually, this i have done already.  I want to add some additional metadata